# inequality between absolute value of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I reading a long proof about complex numbers have a primitive. One step in the proof that I dont understand is why is there an inequality instead of an equalty in the second equation since we just took the absolute value of both sides?

Comment: it's an equality, maybe it's the author's notation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they mean

$\le \dfrac1{|h|}\int_{\alpha}\big|[f(\zeta)-f(z)]\big|d\zeta
$